# Multidimensional std::array

Tags: c++, stl

In C++, how do I create a multidimensional `std::array`? I've tried this:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> arr = {{5, 8, 2}, {8, 3, 1}, {5, 3, 9}};
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: This is an issue that causes some confusion. See the comments to the answer to the duplicate. I am not convinced that your code is really illegal in C++11, but it is not clear-cut.

Comment: That actually should compile I think? The extra braces can be elided.

Comment: Note that there is a [c++14 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3526.html) to fix this.

Comment: @Rapptz I think they can be elided, I also think (but that isn't as clear) that they shouldn't be needed in the first place.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You need extra brackets, until [c++14 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3526.html) kicks in.

```
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> arr = {{{5, 8, 2}, {8, 3, 1}, {5, 3, 9}}};
```

Comment: Can anyone tell, what does every of all these 3 levels of braces means?
And why does also work this: 

    `... = {{ {{5, 8, 2}}, {{...}}, ... }}` (4 levels of braces)?

Comment: @user3241228 my guess: inner=array, next=array-of-arrays, last=uniform initialization.  In your example, you have a 3d array, where the middle rank just happens to have a single element (and that element is a 3-int array).

Comment: The extra brackets are still necessary in C++17. https://godbolt.org/z/8ejr37

Comment: necessary in C++20 too.

Comment: still necessary in C++23 (according to test on GCC13.2, Clang 17.0.1)