# Passing a 3-dimensional variable size array by reference in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

I've been working off of [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function) , as well as a few other similar articles. However, I'm running into a problem wherein the array I'm creating has two dimensions of variable size.

The initialization looks like:

```
int** mulePosition;
mulePosition = new int *[boardSize][boardSize][2];
```

The function looks like:

```
int moveMule (int boardSize, int ***mulePosition)
```

And the references look like

```
moveMule (boardSize, mulePosition)
```

Boardsize is defined at the beginning of the function, but may change per execution.
The array, properly sized, would be int [boardSize][boardSize][2].

Comment: Use some sensible C++ type, like a vector of vectors.

Comment: This initialization is [ill-formed, the types are incompatible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c78ff1c11be7dfd1).

Comment: Yes, the code does not work. The declaration is int** yet the array is 3-dimensional. However, int*** throws its own errors.

Comment: @jbzdarkid That's because `int*[n][n][2]` is a *array of n arrays of n arrays of 2 pointer-to-`int`*. And that's the reason why you typically *don't* want to use these kind of composed types when you have alternatives such as classes wrapping flat data structures or typedefs.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a plain '3-dimensional' array via

```
int* mulePosition = new int[boardsize*boardsize*2];
```

and address its elements calculating the offset from the beginning: mulePosition[a][b][c] is `mulePosition[boardSize*2*a + 2*b + c]`,

or use array of arrays of arrays (which would correspond to your `int***` declaration) or better (and simpler) vector of vectors of vectors, although the initialization would be a little more complex (you would need to initialize every array/vector).

Comment: How would I initialize an array of arrays of arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Either use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` if boardSize is not a const or `std::array<std::array<boardSize>, boardSize>` (see [Multidimensional std::array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759757/multidimensional-stdarray) for how to initialize the std::array).

That being said, it looks like a good idea to hide this in a class Board which provides a nice interface.