# What array structure is in C# but not in C/C++/Java?

Tags: java, c#, c++, c, array-difference

I'm preparing for exams and there's this question I can't find answer to. Read bunch of articles, closest I found was

> Arrays in C# come in three flavors: single-dimensional, multidimensional rectangular arrays (like the C++ multidimensional arrays), and jagged arrays (arrays of arrays).

So this suggests that there's no jagged arrays in C++, but it exists in Java. 
Another thing is that just C# can have non-zero array lower-bound(like a[-1,3] or a[4,9]. Would it be considered different array structure?

Comment: C and C++ also have jagged arrays. You need to create it specifically.

Comment: Why the downvoting? This isn't a very bad question... He could have done some research... but I don't think it is *that* bad.

Comment: @haccks, it doesn't matter. I need an answer to what array structure exists just in C#, if jagged array exists in Java I don't care that it exists in C++ too, or vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**C++**

- *So this suggests that there's no jagged arrays in C++*

By the same reading, the block of text suggests that C++ doesn't have single dimensional arrays. This is clearly absurd!

C++ has both... You clearly can make a `int**`, that is a pointer to a pointer (so an "array" of pointers, so an "array" of "arrays"), like in C# you can have a `int[][]`, that is an array of `int[]`. For C++ see various examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1083658/613130). Note that this syntax is more C than C++... In C++ you should use `std::array`, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17759790/613130).

- *Another thing is that just C# can have non-zero array lower-bound(like a[-1,3] or a[4,9])*

This doesn't exist in C++... They are internally implemented in C# by the same code that implements multi dimensional arrays, and exist for historical reasons (pseudo-compatibility with old versions of VB)

**Java**

Java doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7913679/613130)). It does have jagged arrays, with a trick: if you want you can initialize a jagged array that has all the elements of the same size in a single command *or* if they have different sizes/some of them can be `null`, you can initialize them manually.

```
int[][] num = new int[4][2];
```

vs

```
int[][] num = new int[4][];
num[0] = new int[1];
num[1] = new int[2];
num[2] = new int[3];
num[3] = new int[4];
```

**So in the end**

```
                            C#    Java  C++   
single-dimensional array    x     x     x
multi-dimensional array     x           x
si.di. non-zero based array x
mu.di. non-zero based array x
jagged array                x     x     x
```

Comment: Yeah, so that's the problem, I've read a bunch of what is the same, I need an answer to what array structure exists just in C#. So that non-zero lower-bound would be considered good answer? To me it felt just like some minor difference instead of entirely different array structure.

Comment: @Erndob non-zero lower bound are a complex beast... You can't create them directly in C#, you have to use `Array.CreateInstance` to create them... and their type is the same as the type of other multidimensional array (with the exception of single-dimensional non-zero lower-bound, that uses a special array type). So they are of the same "family" of multi-dimensional array (because they use the same CLR internal classes).

Comment: @Erndob In the end in .NET there are two types of array: "simple arrays": single-dimensional arrays that start with 0, "slow complex arrays": multidimensional or non-0 indexed or both. Jagged arrays are an overstructure that you can put on both of them, because a jagged array is an array of arrays.

Comment: I thought so, so what array structure is in c# but not in java/c++/c ? Because I've read a bunch, and people in this thread answer about things that are the same, not different. Or its just bad question?

Comment: @Erndob See the final table

Comment: So it s non-zero array, thanks.