# Return type of double **function()

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization

I wish to code a function which returns a 2D array or a matrix. Here is my attempt:

```
double **function(){
    double d[2][2] = { { 1.1, 1.2 }, { 2.1, 2.2 } };
    return d; //Error: return type does not match the function type.
}

int main(){
    double d[2][2] = function(); //Error: initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object.
    return 0;
}
```

and I have got error.

Could anyone tell me the correct way or suggest an alternative way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If that worked you'd be returning a dangling reference. Use `std::vector` or some other high-level abstraction and it will just with.

Comment: You could make a drinking game from the questions on StackOverflow that involve array and pointer misunderstandings.

Comment: Go to the whiteboard and write 100 times "an array is not a pointer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays and pointers are rather different. Yes, arrays *do* convert into a pointer to the element type at first opportunity but that does *not* mean that they are the same at all.

The entities you try to convert between have entirely different layout in memory:

- The two dimensional array consists of two arrays of two `double`s which are consecutive in memory.
- The pointer to a pointer to a `double` is an array of *pointers* to `double`.

While both can be used in a form given a rather similar usage experience, they are handled entirely different within the program.

You *can* do this, however (assuming you compile with a C++11 or later compiler):

```
#include <array>

std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 2> function() {
    std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 2> d = { { { 1.1, 1.2 } , { 2.1, 2.2 } } };
    return d;
}

int main(){
    std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 2> d = function();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `double **` with a multidimensional `std::vector` or `std::array` (`std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 2>`). Then your function can return a multidimensional array *by value*. E.g.:

```
std::array<std::array<double,2>, 2> function() {
   std::array<std::array<double,2>, 2> d = { { { 1.1, 1.2 }, { 2.1, 2.2 } } }; 
   // Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759757/multidimensional-stdarray on the syntax to initialize this. 
   return d;
}

int main(){
    std::array<std::array<double,2>, 2> d = function(); 
    return 0;
}
```